# Functional test for Email as Service in Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, functional-testing, swiftmailer

I am trying to write a functional test that checks Email is sent or not. My sendemail method is defined in service so I am not able to follow the example that is given in [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/email/testing.html)

Setup - 
 Controller has a form, When form is submitted and valid it will call sendmail method in the service

> Controller

```
public function sampleAction(Request $request){

   $sampleEntity = new SampleEntity();
   $form = $this->createForm(sampleType::class, $sampleEntity)
   $form->handleRequest($request);
   if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
      ...
      $sampleservice = $this->get('sampleservice');
      $sampleservice->sendMail();

      return $this->render('sample/formsubmitted.html.twig');
   }
}
```

> Service

```
public function sendMail(){

        $body = $this->renderTemplate();

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Sample Mail')
            ->setFrom($this->sender_mail)
            ->setTo($this->admin_mail)
            ->setBody($body);

        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }
```

> Test

```
public function testEmailSend(){

        $client = static::createClient();

        $client->enableProfiler();
        $crawler = $client->request('POST', '/sampleform');
        $client->followRedirects(false);

        $form = $crawler->selectButton('Submit Form')->form();

        $crawler = $client->submit($form);

        $mailCollector = $client->getProfile()->getCollector('swiftmailer');

        $this->assertEquals(1, $mailCollector->getMessageCount());

    }
```

Can this line be explained better `$crawler = $client->request('POST', '/sampleform');` , in cookbook it says path to sendmail action but since it is not action in my case, what to write there or do I have to take whole new approach?

Apart from this I tried calling sendmail directly from service, assertEqual is giving me 0 since sendmail is not accessed(I guess). Any ideas on where and how to proceed. This is my first attempt to write functional tests so if I made some obvious mistake pardon me.

> Edit 1

SampleType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){

   $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array('data' => 'Sample'))
            ->add('phone', TextType::class, array('data' => '1234567890'))
->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit Form'))
            ->getForm();    
}
```

Edit 2 
When tried calling service directly, Is there any other way to call service directly ?

```
public function testEmailSend(){

        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->enableProfiler();
        $crawler = $client->request('POST', '/src/AppBundle/Service/SampleService/sendMail()');

        $mailCollector = $client->getProfile()->getCollector('swiftmailer');

        $this->assertEquals(1, $mailCollector->getMessageCount());

    }
```

This one returns "Failed asserting that 0 matches expected 1."

Mail gets send successfully in the Application, But want to make sure in test as well

Comment: Are you sure the test goes into the `if ($form->isSubmitted()... ` action ? Because you post without values. What your form type look like ?

Comment: Ya, I have wrote the test when `if ()` is true. I have already wrote tests for both true and false. So trying to extend the true test for sendmail as well. Lets just assume all the value in the form have predefined data in it.

Comment: Try with a get action with only a call to your email service. Does it work in dev mode ?

Comment: You mean, In controller call the email service without the form submission ? and then check in test ?

Comment: From what I see in the cookbook entry, the `enableProfiler` only enables the profiler for the next request. Your submit is the second request. Enable the profiler before the form submit in your test.

Comment: Also in your `config_test.yml` do you have `profiler` `enabled` and `collect`?
See bottom of this page: http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/profiling.html

Comment: Great! It worked. Ya I had profiler enabled in config. Can you post it as an answer. So that it might help others, if they have same problem. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in the cookbook entry, the `enableProfiler` only enables the profiler for the **next request**. Your submit is the second request. Enable the profiler before the form submit in your test.

Also in your `config_test.yml` do you have profiler `enabled: true` and `collect: true`? See bottom of this page: [How to Use the Profiler in a Functional Test](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/profiling.html#speeding-up-tests-by-not-collecting-profiler-data)

**Test**

```
public function testEmailSend(){

        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('POST', '/sampleform');
        $client->followRedirects(false);

        $form = $crawler->selectButton('Submit Form')->form();

        $client->enableProfiler();
        $crawler = $client->submit($form);

        $mailCollector = $client->getProfile()->getCollector('swiftmailer');

        $this->assertEquals(1, $mailCollector->getMessageCount());

    }
```